# List all packages available on CRAN to console

Tags: r

Would like to get a list of all packages available on CRAN to the windows console.  I know that it's gotta be pretty easy because on the windows gui there's an manu option to click install, at which time another menu interface pops up with all packages available on CRAN.  If the menu were a function (which it probably is I just don't know what it is) I'd look at the code and figure out how they get that list.

So what you see here: ([packages alphabetical LINK](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)) I'd like to get to the console so I can assign it to an object.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a duplicate question but a duplicate answer.  That poster was asking something more specific.  Granted this question resulted from a poor search but I think the title and question are clear and can be of use to further searchers.

Comment: Fair enough. And your title is certainly perfectly constructed to lead future searchers to the right place. (Though apparently it would be even easier to find if you edited it to read "List all packages available packages ..."!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?available.packages` did not appear in the results of your search?  You did search before asking, didn't you? ;-)

Comment: more specifically, `a1 <- available.packages(); rownames(a1)`

Comment: Yes I searched but poorly, using google.  I just checked and `findFn` from `sos` returned what I wanted in seconds.  My apologies.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I bet you would have found it had you searched for "available packages" instead of "packages available". :)

Comment: Your suspicions are confirmed.  I just tried searching that way and surprisingly I get different results.  I didn't know word order mattered in a google search.