# List of all packages available on Bioconductor

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I know how to get the list of all available packages on CRAN ([Names of R's available packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381932/names-of-rs-available-packages) and [List all packages available on CRAN to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638792/list-all-packages-available-on-cran-to-console)) with the `available.packages()` function.

But how can I get the list of packages available on [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have the list of packages with :

```
BiocManager::available()
```

Don't forget to install the package (`install.packages("BiocManager")`)

Answer (score 4):

If you need more info than just the list:

```r
df <- read.dcf(
    url("https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES")
)
as.data.frame(df)
```